# How can I show a specific word in a data set?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, find

I just started to learn python. I have a question about matching some of the words in my dataset in excel.

words_list is included some of the words I would like to find in a dataset.

```
words_list = ('tried','mobile','abc')
```

df is the extract from excel and picked up a single column.

```
df =

0        to make it possible or easier for someone to do ...  
1        unable to acquire a buffer item very likely ...  
2        The organization has tried to make...  
3        Broadway tried a variety of mobile Phone for the..
```

I would like to get the result like this:

```
'None',
'None',
'tried',
'tried','mobile'
```

I tried in Jupiter like this:

```
list = [ ]
for word in df: 
    if any (aa in word for aa in words_List): 
        list.append(word) 
    else:
        list.append('None')

print(list)
```

But the result will show the whole sentence in df

```
'None'  
'None'  
'The organization has tried to make...'  
'Broadway tried a variety of mobile Phone for the..'
```

Can I only show the result only in the words list?
Sorry for my English and
thank you all

Comment: whatr EXACT output format do you want ? Please write precisly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest a manipulation on the `DataFrame` (that should always be your first thought, use the power of pandas)

```
import pandas as pd

words_list = {'tried', 'mobile', 'abc'}

df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['to make it possible or easier for someone to do',
                           'unable to acquire a buffer item very likely',
                           'The organization has tried to make',
                           'Broadway tried a variety of mobile Phone for the']})

df['matches'] = df['col'].str.split().apply(lambda x: set(x) & words_list)
print(df)


                                                col          matches
0   to make it possible or easier for someone to do               {}
1       unable to acquire a buffer item very likely               {}
2                The organization has tried to make          {tried}
3  Broadway tried a variety of mobile Phone for the  {mobile, tried}
```

Comment: Some explanation on what happens inside the lambda would be helpful since OP is a beginner.

Comment: Thanks @azro! If I want to remove the bracket for each word in the matches columns, how can I do ?

I tried this code but it doesn't work 
Remove=df['matches'].replace(['{', '}'],[' ',' '], regex=True)

Comment: Because I need these selected words in matches for sentiment analysis, the sentiment analysis doesn't support TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's printing the whole line has to do with your:

```
for word in df:
```

Your "word" variable is actually taking the whole line.  Then it's checking the whole line to see if it contains your search word.  If it does find it, then it basically says, "yes, I found ____ in this line, so append the line to your list.

What it sounds like you want to do is first split the line into words, and THEN check.

```
list = [ ]
found = False

for line in df:
    words = line.split(" ") 
    for word in word_list:
       if word in words:
          found = True
          list.append(word)
    # this is just to append "None" if nothing found
    if found:
       found = False
    else:
       list.append("None")
        
print(list)
```

As a side note, you may want to use pprint instead of print when working with lists.  It prints lists, dictionaries, etc in easier to read layouts.  I don't know if you'll need to install the package.  That depends on how you initially installed python.  But usage would be something like:

```
from pprint import pprint

dictionary = {'firstkey':'firstval','secondkey':'secondval','thirdkey':'thirdval'}

pprint(dictionary)
```